# java add two arrays in parallel

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, parallel-processing

I already found this question here, but it be great to see more options.
[How to add two arrays in Java in parallel manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686642/how-to-add-two-arrays-in-java-in-parallel-manner)

I have 2 float/ double arrays (around 10.000 to 100.000 entries) where I need to perform component wise operations on (e.g. division, multiplication, addition).

I'm working on a PC with 4 to 32 CPUs, thus I'd love to use this power and execute these computations in parallel in a Java environment.

What are good ways to do that in Java?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: A duplicate question is still a duplicate, even though IntStream is relatively new

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
    double [] t0 = {....};
    double [] t1 = {....};
    double [] result =new double[t0.length];
    IntStream.range(0, t0.length).parallel().forEach(i -> result[i] = t0[i] + t1[i]);
```